# Programmatically login in dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, authentication, dotnetnuke-5

hey guys,
i am using dotnetnuke as my CMS, for some reason i want to manually login user into the site, i am able to login but the problem is, even if i enter the invalid password, still dotnetnuke log me in. i am using below code.

```
UserInfo objUser = new UserInfo();

objUser.Username = Login1.UserName;
UserMembership objMembership = new UserMembership(objUser);
objMembership.Username = Login1.UserName;
objMembership.Password = Login1.Password;
objUser.Membership = objMembership;

//UserCreateStatus result = UserController.CreateUser(ref objUser);                
UserController.UserLogin(0, objUser, Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"], this.Request.UserHostAddress, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var loginStatus = UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_FAILURE;

var Login=UserController.UserLogin(0, UserName, Password, “”, “”, “”, ref loginStatus, false);                   

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, “Logged in Successfully”);
```

For more details you can refer the following link -

https://codevanar.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/password-encryption-and-decryption-in-dnn-and-log-in-programmatically/