# able to login to dotnetnuke with incorrect password

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I am able to login to dnn website with incorrect password. When i click on login button after typing incorrect password, it gives me the proper validation message. However, I am logged in because if I refresh or browse the site pages, I get access and I can see my screen name.

I am using dnn version 7.1.2

On login button click, I am using the below C# code:

```
var user = UserController.UserLogin(
            portalId, userName, password, string.Empty,
            portalName, ipAddress, ref loginStatus, checked);
```

Values for each :

```
portId = 0
ipAddress = ::1
var loginStatus = UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_FAILURE;
var checked = false;
```

Below is the configuation for the membership.

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
          connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" 
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
          enablePasswordReset="true" 
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
          minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
          requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
          passwordFormat="Hashed" 
          applicationName="DotNetNuke" 
          description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database"/>
```

Any help here. I checked the link mentioned below, which has the same core issue but havent got any solution from the suggestion there.

[Programmatically login in dotnetnuke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835918/programmatically-login-in-dotnetnuke)

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do in my authentication provider:

```
var loginStatus = UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_FAILURE;
UserInfo user = UserController.ValidateUser(portalId, userName, password, string.Empty, string.Empty, Request.UserHostAddress.ToString(), ref loginStatus);

bool authenticated = (loginStatus == UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS || loginStatus == UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_SUPERUSER);
var eventArgs = new UserAuthenticatedEventArgs(user, user.Username, loginStatus, "DNN");
eventArgs.Authenticated = authenticated;
OnUserAuthenticated(eventArgs);
```

Comment: Yeah. I figured out almost the same kind of approach. I called the UserController.ValidateUser method as per your suggestion. Based on the loginStatus, I am calling the UserController.UserLogin. :) Seemd to be working fine.

Comment: Sam, good to hear. This code was lifted from an Authentication provider therefore I am using the OnUserAuthentication event from the AuthenticationLoginBase. I should have clarified that.